# How do you create indicators?

Tags: indicator, programming, development, application-development

Where could I find some documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may also want to have a look at the [AppIndicator Reference Manual](http://people.canonical.com/~ted/libappindicator/current/AppIndicator.html).

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I've found this site:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators

I'm not sure how I haven't been able to find it before.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time figuring this out as well, with Python, PyGObject and GTK3. I've made a minimal working example that could also help you to get started: https://bitbucket.org/cpbotha/indicator-cpuspeed/src